# Visual Studio Code 1.28.2 and GitHub signed commits using password-protected GPG key

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, gpg-signature

Does anybody know if there's a way to make VS Code ask for the GPG password when signing the commits?

I feel somehow uncomfortable having to use a password-less GPG key to do so.

Answer (score -2):

A bit late, but with the current version of VS Code (1.38) you only have to enable commit signing, by adding this to your `settings.json`:

```
"git.enableCommitSigning": true
```

Or you can open the settings tab, search for "gpg" and activate the checkbox "Enables commit signing with GPG".

If you have a GPG key with password, VS Code opens a separate GUI Window on commit:

[image]

See [this article](https://medium.com/@devmount/signed-git-commits-in-vs-code-476fb74b8773) about signed commits in VS Code.